# Was my edit rightfully rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I made an edit to [Semicolon before self-invoking function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7365172/3684713) today, but it was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11313543), stating that the edit deviates from the original intent. However, all I did was remove an edit which included the answer into the body of the question, as well as add a tag and remove some unnecessary fluff.

> Thanks in advance guys

Was my edit wrongfully rejected or am I misjudging the situation?

Comment: Your edit looks reasonable to me, except for the addition of the [semicolon] tag. Why is that a useful tag?

Comment: @CodyGray [tag:semicolon-insertion] might have been better, but that didn't exist. The question this question is a duplicate of is also tagged [tag:semicolon]. Since this question is really very specifically about semicolons, it seemed reasonable.

Comment: There are 3 rejects on 4 votes. The reason of reject is same. So i would say that these persons didn't have looked to the edit reason. There is plenty of reviewers who doesn't read the summary I think.. When in doubt, i check the actual post to understand the edit to make a concise action.

Comment: These reviewers just raced through the review queue, spending less than 10 seconds per review.   The deletion of the code snippet was surely the Red Button offense they saw and they stopped looking. 10 seconds is not enough to get the job done properly, a very common issue.  Sorry, you were unlucky to get these three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This edit was wrongfully rejected.

The reviewers probably just saw a lot of code being removed, and didn't realize it was something that the asker should have posted as an answer - long ago. Given that the question has a highly upvoted, accepted answer, no information is lost by this edit.

You also clearly pointed out what you did, and why, in the edit summary.

As @Cody Gray and you point out in the comments, the [semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semicolon) tag might be debatable, but the question is definitely about the semantics of the semicolon.

Comment: Yeah, given the existence of a [semicolon] tag, he probably wasn't wrong to add it. I suppose I would just question the purpose of such a tag. Who can be an expert in [semicolon]? It is indeed a semicolon-related syntax issue, but all syntax issues are language-specific. No one is an expert in semicolon usage in C++ *and* Javascript; they are very different languages with different specifications.

Comment: @CodyGray come to think of it, you're probably right. [tag:semicolon] should maybe be burninated and possibly be made a synonym of [tag:syntax].